# SQL group by in joined tables

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to extract data from two tables of a SQL server. Below query runs perfectly with out "group by" however when I try to group data by b.catdesc and a.fiscal_ year it shows below error.

ERROR: [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0122
- Column COUNTRY_CODE or expression in SELECT list not valid.
Error
Code: -122
Report User

```
SELECT  a.country_code,
a.book,
b.catunitdesc,
b.catdesc,
b.csku_cc,
sum(a.gross_sales),
a.fiscal_year,
a.fiscal_week,
a.fiscal_month,
sum(a.gross_costs),
sum(a.net_sales),
sum(a.net_costs),
sum(a.qty_shipped_gross),
sum(a.qty_shipped_net)

FROM essv11.eudmeas2 a
join essv11.eudmp1 b
on a.sku_cc = b.sku_cc

WHERE book = 'G21-2014' 
OR book = 'G21-2015'
OR book = 'G21-2016'
AND Country_code ='GB' 
GROUPED BY b.catdesc, a.fiscal_year;
```

Can anyone please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You say 'SQL Server' but the error you posted is an ODBC Driver to an IBM DB2 database, not a SQL Server database. SQL Server uses "GROUP BY" not "GROUPED BY".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include all non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY`.  I would suggest:

```
SELECT  a.country_code, a.book, b.catunitdesc, b.catdesc, b.csku_cc,
        sum(a.gross_sales),
        a.fiscal_year, a.fiscal_week, a.fiscal_month,
        sum(a.gross_costs),
        sum(a.net_sales),
        sum(a.net_costs),
        sum(a.qty_shipped_gross),
        sum(a.qty_shipped_net)
from essv11.eudmeas2 a join
     essv11.eudmp1 b
     on a.sku_cc = b.sku_cc
where book in ('G21-2014', 'G21-2015', 'G21-2016') and
      Country_code = 'GB' 
group by a.country_code, a.book, b.catunitdesc, b.catdesc, b.csku_cc,
         a.fiscal_year, a.fiscal_week, a.fiscal_month;
```

Note:

- The `group by` has all the non-aggregated columns.
- `IN` is better than a series of `=`/`or`

Comment: IN is definitely more elegant (and less prone to human error). But is there a performance benefit?

Comment: @Strawberry . . . In this case, it probably fixes a logical problem in the OP's query.  Performance would be secondary to writing the correct logic.

Answer (score 0):

All elements on the select list either must come from functions such as SUM, or must be on the GROUP BY list.
Your first selection (country_code) is not on the GROUP BY, making the database report that error.

You can either add a.country_code, a.book, b.catunitdesc, b.csku_cc, a.fiscal_week, a.fiscal_month to the GROUP BY, or remove them from the select list.

Probably you should remove from the select, because it doesn't make sense to get fiscal week or fiscal month when you are grouping by year.